# PHP flock() with compress.zlib:// doesn't work?

Tags: php

Trying to lock a stream using flock but it's not working.

```
$handle = fopen('/path/to/file.txt', 'r');
flock($handle, LOCK_EX); // Returns true

$handle = fopen('compress.zlib:///path/to/file.txt', 'r');
flock($handle, LOCK_EX); // Returns false
```

Why ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't lock streams in general -- while `compress.zlib` streams do (typically*) refer to a file, most other types of streams (such as `http://` streams) do not represent distinct files, so it usually doesn't make sense to lock them.

*: An exception is nested streams (e.g, `compress.zlib://http://example.com/`).